# SQL combine two select across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

So I've these tables:

Table 1:

```
facilities   emails
Fac 1        fac1@email.com
Fac 2        fac2@email.com
Fac 1 RE     fac1@email.com
```

Table 2:

```
facilities  emails
fac1        fac1@email.com
fac2        fac3@email.com
```

Now, on those two tables, I am trying to figure out how many facilities are using each address email. I have two sql queries that do just that:

```
SELECT ce.email, count(*)  
AS TOTAL_FACILITIES 
FROM table1 
AS ce 
GROUP BY ce.email
ORDER BY TOTAL_FACILITIES DESC

SELECT ca.emails, count(*)  
AS TOTAL_FACILITIES 
FROM table2 
AS ca 
GROUP BY ca.emails
ORDER BY TOTAL_FACILITIES DESC
```

This gives me the different emails from each table and how many facilities use them. I'm now  trying to combine it into a single call using a join but I can't seem to figure out how to make the count work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT A.emails, COUNT(*) as total_facilities
FROM
(SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2) A
GROUP BY A.emails
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: That indeed does it. I was about to post on eric's answer pointing out that union does put results from different tables near each other which makes it easy to add them up but doesn't actually do the addition. However, doing the union before aggregating does do it if you put in an alias. Since you did use the alias, I'm giving you the answer. Thanks y'all :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to `UNION` it instead.

```
SELECT ce.email, count(*) AS TOTAL_FACILITIES 
FROM table1 AS ce 
GROUP BY ce.email
UNION
SELECT ca.emails, count(*) AS TOTAL_FACILITIES 
FROM table2 AS ca 
GROUP BY ca.emails
ORDER BY TOTAL_FACILITIES DESC
```

A better solution is to UNION it before aggregating.

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_FACILITIES
FROM (
    SELECT facilities, email
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT facilities, email
    FROM table2
)
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY TOTAL_FACILITIES DESC
```